# Why would iron-router ignore waitOn?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

`onAfterAction` is run twice, once before the data arrives, and once after. Why is it run before the data arrives? Also, in this basic version, `rendered` is called after the data arrives, but in my app, it's called before the data arrives. Any idea why that might be? Basic reproduction:

https://github.com/lorensr/waiton-bug

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection 'items'

Router.configure
  waitOn: ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'items'

if Meteor.isServer
  Meteor.publish 'items', ->
    Items.find {}

Router.route '/',
  name: 'hello'
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldnt waitOn RETURN an ARRAY? You just subscribe without any return or an array.

Comment: You don't have to return an array - you can return a single subscription instead.

Comment: Right, probably I got this habit from old API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `loadingTemplate` defined. Iron Router can't use the loading template if you don't have one so the effect is the waiting effect of `waitOn` is ignored.

Simply add the loadingTemplate and it should work.

The `onAfterAction` is run once and after. The first when its waiting, the other times when there is a reactive change or the data is ready. If you want something that doesn't do this use `onRun` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the Router to what for a collection subscription. The collection and the subscription both are reactive data sources. So when that collection changes, the waitOn fill fire and update the route including the onAfterAction.